# Notice: Undefined variable: on line 24

Tags: variables, mysqli

I have the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){ $res = $_POST['id']; } 
if(isset($_POST['ora2'])){ $oratwo = $_POST['ora2']; } 
$operator = $_SESSION['login'];
$order = "
UPDATE  `frontdes_dep`.`flux_receptie` 
SET  `status_preluare` =  'ALOCAT',  `ora_preluare` =$oratwo,  `operator_preluare` =$operator 
WHERE  `flux_receptie`.`id` =$res";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $order);
```

When I press the submit button which take actions above, it returns me error:
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: oratwo in C:\wamp\www\interfata_client.php on line 24
The code is working because when I look into DB, the columns populate with values.

Line 24 is the line with $order = ...

The submit is in an echo:

```
echo "<div id='example3'>

    <form style='padding:15px 0px 0px 0px' id='interfata' name ='interfata' method='POST' action='interfata_client.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$res[0]'>
    <input type='hidden' name='ora2' value='now()'>
    <input type='submit' name='name' value='ALOCARE'>
    </form>
    <td><center>preluat de:<p><b>$res[8]</center></b></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <br>
    ";
```

Does anynone know what am I doing wrong? I have WAMP installed.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['ora2']` and `$oratwo` are set?

Comment: `$oratwo` is not defined. It is because `$_POST['ora2']` is not set. Make sure that values are coming in `$_POST['ora2']`.Try to echo `$_POST['ora2']`. Before it goes in condition and then check.

Comment: The submit is in an echo. Please see the post updated. Maybe because the input is "hidden" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get rid of this issue , The first one is to ignore the issue by turning of Notice exceptions .

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE );
```

Or try the second solution below.

> Notice : check whether the value is coming up from the form ('ora2')
>   before trying the second one.

Your code

```
  if(isset($_POST['ora2'])){ $oratwo = $_POST['ora2']; }
```

Updated code

```
  if(isset($_POST['ora2'])){ 
        $oratwo = isset($_POST['ora2']) ? $_POST['ora2'] : '';
   }
```

Comment: The values are coming. I checked the DB.